# How do I ensure that a string will return properly in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, return, return-type

I was building a bit of code that would trim off any non-digit entries from the start and end of a string, I had a very confusing issue with the following bit of code:

```
def String_Trim(Raw_String):
        if Raw_String[0].isdigit() == False:
            New_String = Raw_String[1:]
            String_Trim(New_String)
        elif Raw_String[-1].isdigit() == False:
            New_String = Raw_String[:-1]
            String_Trim(New_String)
        else:
            print Raw_String
            return Raw_String

print(String_Trim('ab19fsd'))
```

The initial printing of Raw_String works fine and displays the value that I want (19), but for some reason, the last line trying to print the return value of String_Trim returns a None. What exactly is python doing here and how can I fix it? Any other comments about improving my code would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - it suggests a different naming style (lowercase_with_underscores) and you should avoid `== True` and ´== False´ (they are not necessary, `if foo` and `if not foo` are the proper ways to check a boolean for true/false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex for this. Recursion for trimming a string is really not a good idea:

```
import re

def trim_string(string):
  return re.sub(r'^([^0-9]+)(.*?)([^0-9]+)$', r'\2', string)
```

To break it down, the regex (`r'^([^0-9]+)(.*?)([^0-9]+)$'`) is like so:

- `^` matches the start of a string.
- `([^0-9]+)` matches a group of consecutive non-digit characters.
- `(.*?)` matches a group of stuff (non-greedy).
- `([^0-9]+)` matches another group of consecutive non-digit characters.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

The replacement string, `r'\2'`, just says to replace the matched string with only the second group, which is the stuff between the two groups of non-digit characters.

---

But if you're *really* sure you want to use your existing solution, you need to understand how recursion actually works. When you call `return foo`, the function returns `foo` as its output. If you don't call `return`, you return `None` automatically.

That being said, you need to `return` in every case of the recursion process, not just at the end:

```
def String_Trim(Raw_String):
    if Raw_String[0].isdigit() == False:
        New_String = Raw_String[1:]
        return String_Trim(New_String)
    elif Raw_String[-1].isdigit() == False:
        New_String = Raw_String[:-1]
        return String_Trim(New_String)
    else:
        print Raw_String
        return Raw_String
```

Comment: Why is recursion for trimming a string so bad?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: And you could get a stack overflow exception if there are a lot of characters that need trimming.

Comment: @Shep: Not just slow in Python - it's slow in almost every language that has immutable strings. Removing one character at a time creates lots new strings, copying the contents of the string each time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the feedback, but I'm still unclear as to why the original code didn't work. Also, thanks for the regex explanation.

Comment: See my answer once more. Your recursion logic wasn't `return`ing sometimes.

Comment: Regex usage isn't a privilege, it should be a last resort. `Raw_String.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')` is cleaner.

Comment: @JosefAssad: You're solving a different problem than I was, as we interpreted the question differently. The goal was to `.lstrip()` and `.rstrip()` all non-numbers from the string. For example, `asd12x3asd` would get trimmed to `12x3`, not `123`.

Comment: I'm not solving a different problem. Have a read of .strip's docstring or try the line in my comment if you're feeling lazy.

Comment: .strip() is nice but there are more non-digit characters than just lowercase letters.

Comment: Your regex code can be simplified down to `re.sub(r'^\D+|\D+$', '', s)`

Answer (score 1):

You return a value in only one case inside `StringTrim`. Add `return` in front of the recursive calls:

```
        return String_Trim(New_String)
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Tried it, but sadly it still returns Nones

Comment: Understood and implemented now, thank you. Moot due to the changing of the code, but still useful for improving my coding abilities.

Comment: It doesn't return Nones; this is the correct answer considering that the question was not requesting alternate approaches to the recursive solution but was asking why te recursive solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return only the digits from a string; because "trim of any non digits from the start and end" to me sounds like "return only numbers".

If that's correct, you can do this:

```
''.join(a for a in 'abc19def' if a.isdigit())
```

Comment: That'll strip out non-digits surrounded by digits in the string. I'm not sure if it's just a typo in the question, but the OP specifically needed a solution that stripped out non-digits from both sides of the string.

Comment: You have a point, but how do you know how long a string is? Or for that matter what is the "start" and "end". After reading this `and displays the value that I want (19)` - I figured I'd throw it out.

Comment: Blender is correct, this is basically for throwing away useless information in a genetic algorithm, so this would sadly not work. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: What does string theory have to do with string objects in Python?

Comment: @Blender - err .. sorry about that one, it was a wrong paste. Edited.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I'd totally do this approach if it weren't for the wording in the question.

Comment: Weird, I actually thought @BurhanKhalid was referring to out am [established problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Number_of_solutions) with string theory.